# Django | ORM | Get records that are divisible by an integer

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, orm

Using Django's ORM, is it possible to query the db for records that has a column with value that is divisible by an integer?

For example, get only records that their `num` column is divisible by 2 (`num % 2 == 0`).

I hope that this is clear enough.

THANKS!!

Comment: That's to general, what did you try so far? Any code snippets that didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [F() with annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) (from Django 1.8), to create a dynamic field (`nummod2`) on your models by combining different fields with arithmetic, then filter the dynamic field like this:

```
Company.objects.annotate(nummod2=F('num')%2).filter(nummod2=0)
```